# Setprecision and file

Tags: c++, decimal, rounding

I have 2 questions:
1. How do I make it so that if a certain file isn't entered, it wont proceed?
2. My numbers wont show the decimal points and I'm not understanding why, I used `setprecision`

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip> 
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        ifstream inFile;
        ofstream outFile;
        string file;
        int Bailey , 
            Harrison, 
            Grant, 
            Peterson, 
            Hsu, 
            Bowles, 
            Anderson, 
            Nguyen, 
            Sharp, 
            Jones, 
            McMillan, 
            Gabriel;
        int m, f , cc, un;


        cout << "                  Welcome to Maggie's Student Survey!"; //Introduction
       cout << endl;
       cout << " Enter the file name you wish to open: " <<endl;// promts  the user to enter the file name they want to open
        getline(cin, file);
        inFile.open(file);
        outFile.open(file);
        cout << " The Student's Genders, Colleges, and Scores:" << endl;
        cout << "\n Bailey           M CC 68"
            "\n Harrison         F CC 71"
            "\n Grant            M UN 75"
            "\n Peterson         F UN 69"
            "\n Hsu              M UN 79"
            "\n Bowles           M CC 75"
            "\n Anderson         F UN 64"
            "\n Nguyen           F CC 68"
            "\n Sharp            F CC 75"
            "\n Jones            M UN 75"
            "\n McMillan         F UN 80"
            "\n Gabriel          F UN 62 " << endl; //the data file so the       user can see what they opened
        m = (75 + 79 + 75 + 75) / 4; // average will be 76
        f = (71 + 69 + 64 + 68 + 75 + 80 + 62) / 7; //average will be 69.85
        cc = (71 + 75 + 68 + 75) / 4; //average will be 72.25
        un = (75 + 69 + 79 + 64 + 75 + 80 + 62) / 7; // average will be 72
        cout << " Total Males Average Scores: " << std::setprecision(2) << m  << endl;
        cout << " Total Females Average Scores: " << std::setprecision(2) << f << endl;
        cout << " Total Community College Average Scores " << std::setprecision(2) << cc << endl;
        cout << " Total University Average Scores: " << std::setprecision(2) << un    << endl;

        system("pause");
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to your second question, I came up with a solution that first you need to declare m, f, cc, un as doubles, not ints.
Then try storing the other numbers as other variables. For example for cc:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip> 


int main()
{    
    double a, b, c, d; // or ints, here it doesn't matter
    a = 71;
    b = 75;
    c = 68;
    d = 75;
    double cc = (a + b + c + d) / 4; //average will be 72.25
    std::cout << " Total Community College Average Scores " << std::setprecision(4) << cc << '\n';
    system("pause");
}
```

If you do it like this, the precision works. I set it to 4 in order to display your number, 2 is not enough.

Other solution (maybe easier):

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip> 


int main()
{   
    double p;
    p = 71 + 75 + 68 + 75;
    double cc = p / 4; //average will be 72.25
    std::cout << " Total Community College Average Scores " << std::setprecision(4) << cc << '\n';
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by falco addresses how you need to change your average variables to be `doubles`. Additionally, I would divide by `4.0` instead of `4` to make the floating point division more explicit. Otherwise, you may end up performing integer division and get expected results.

The following example should get you started on making the program not proceed if the file doesn't exist. I'm assuming that is what you mean by "if a certain file isn't entered".

```
    std::cout << "Enter the file name you wish to open: " << std::endl;
    std::getline( std::cin, filename );

    std::ifstream inFile( filename, std::ios::in );
    if ( !inFile )
    {
        // return if the file couldn't be opened
        return 1;
    }

    // write some stuff to the file
```